# How to find the argument of the dot product of two complex vectors?

Tags: inner-products

I have two complex vectors $\mathbb{a}$ and $\mathbb{b}$ I want to find $\arg(c)$ where $$c=\langle\mathbb{a},\mathbb{b}\rangle.$$ That is $c$ is the inner product of the two vectors. Thank you.

Comment: In terms of what?

Comment: @SaucyO'Path I do not understand what you mean by "In terms of what?" Argument means the angle between the real component and imaginary component of $c$

Comment: That much is clear. But, for instance, what's wrong with $\operatorname{arg}\sum\limits_{k=1}^n \overline a_kb_k$ (or the other way around, I don't know where you put the sesquilinear component)?

Comment: What Saucy meant was something along the lines of the fact that "The argument of $c$ is equal to the argument of $\langle a,b\rangle$" is, at the moment, a valid answer the way you've phrased the question. However, it's probably not the answer you're after. What kind of answer are you after?

Comment: Ok I understand. I mean can we say that argument of $c$ is $$\frac{\mathbb{a^Hb}}{\|\mathbb{a^Hb\|}}$$ or something like that? where $H$means the hermitian transpose

Answer (score 5):

Hint:

since the argument of a complex number $z$ is 
$$
\theta=\arctan \frac{Im (z)}{Re (z)}
$$
you can use the fact that, with the definition of the inner product,

$$
\langle\mathbb{a},\mathbb{b}\rangle=\sum_{i=1}^n \overline{a_i}b_i
$$

so that 
$$
\overline{\langle\mathbb{a},\mathbb{b}\rangle}=\sum_{i=1}^n \overline{b_i}a_i=\langle\mathbb{b},\mathbb{a}\rangle
$$
we have:

$$Im (\langle\mathbb{a},\mathbb{b}\rangle)=\frac{1}{2i}(\langle\mathbb{a},\mathbb{b}\rangle-\langle\mathbb{b},\mathbb{a}\rangle)$$

and

$$Re (\langle\mathbb{a},\mathbb{b}\rangle)=\frac{1}{2}(\langle\mathbb{a},\mathbb{b}\rangle+\langle\mathbb{b},\mathbb{a}\rangle)$$

---

putting in the definition of $\theta$ we can find:

$$
\theta=\arctan \left(-i\frac{\langle\mathbb{a},\mathbb{b}\rangle)-\langle\mathbb{b},\mathbb{a}\rangle)}{\langle\mathbb{a},\mathbb{b}\rangle)+\langle\mathbb{b},\mathbb{a}\rangle)} \right) =
\arctan \left(-i\frac{\langle\mathbb{a},\mathbb{b}\rangle)^2-\langle\mathbb{b},\mathbb{a}\rangle)^2}{|\langle\mathbb{a},\mathbb{b}\rangle)+\langle\mathbb{b},\mathbb{a}\rangle)|^2} \right)
$$

Comment: thank you for your Hint. Since this hint will lead to some final answer. Please write that final answer and I will try my best to reach the answer with the above hint. With only the hint I am unable to proceed so I request you to please right the final expression. Thank you again.

Comment: @FrankMoses -- Put the last expressions for Re and Im into the first expression for $\theta$.

Comment: @mr_e_man thank you. I have put it but it does not reduce to a simpler expression

Comment: @FrankMoses -- Why do you expect it to simplify? Isn't this good enough?

Comment: I added something to my  answer, but the ''simpler'' expression depends on what you want.

Comment: @mr_e_man actually I am seeking the answer to this question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2815478/how-to-show-that-following-is-a-solution-of-the-optimization-problem. I think the simplified expression would help to solve that question